# Silent iOS Push Notification with React Native when app is in background

Tags: ios, push-notification, react-native

I have a React Native app where I am trying to get a silent iOS push notification sent to a handler in JavaScript.

The behaviour I am seeing is that the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function in `AppDelegate` gets called but my handler in JavaScript doesn't get called unless the app is in the foreground or has only been closed recently.

The thing I am confused about is clearly the app is being woken up and having it's `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function called, but then the call to `[RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification]` doesn't seem to do anything.

Also, if I open the app after a notification has been received, then I see the React Native handler is called at that point.

My `didReceiveRemoteNotification` function looks like this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification
{
  NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification");

  [RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
}
```

In the Root component of my React Native app I have this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);

    PushNotificationIOS.addEventListener('notification', (notification) => {
        console.log("notification recieved");
    })
}
handleAppStateChange(currentAppState) {
    console.log(currentAppState);
}
```

I am sending a push notification using AWS SNS with the following message:

```
{
"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\":{\"content-available\":\"1\"}}"
}
```

Here is the log from XCode:

```
2016-04-20 10:38:01.255 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] inactive
2016-04-20 10:38:01.986 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] background
2016-04-20 10:38:17.279 test[4056:1383261] didReceiveRemoteNotification
2016-04-20 10:38:17.284 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] notification recieved
2016-04-20 10:44:56.330 test[4056:1383261] didReceiveRemoteNotification
2016-04-20 10:44:56.332 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] notification recieved
2016-04-20 10:46:07.091 test[4056:1383261] didReceiveRemoteNotification
2016-04-20 10:49:30.039 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] notification recieved
2016-04-20 10:49:30.639 [info][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] active
```

In this log, 3 push notifications where sent. The ones received at 10:38 and 10:44 both called JavaScript correctly.
However, the one received at 10:46 didn't call the handler in JavaScript until I opened the app at 10:49.

Is there anything I can do to ensure the call to my React Native code occurs even with app not running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for notifications to hit your app in the background you need to also define a fetchCompletionHandler, with a completion handler function like below. The `aps:{content-available:1}` payload should wake up you application and trigger this code in your AppDelegate, and in turn hit your JavaScript in RN.

```
// fetch notifications in the background and foreground
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification 
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

[RCTPushNotificationManager didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
NSLog(@"Notification Body %@", notification);

}
```

Comment: i am working on the same feature, when my app is killed/inactive, silent notification is not received when the next time i open the app. have i done something wrong?  or this is how the silent notification works that it won't be received if the app was inactive ? @BrienCrean

Comment: This should really be in the react-native documentation

Comment: any idea how to differentiate between whether the notification was received in the foreground or background?